# Why use Redis if it's not being run on your application server?

Tags: database, redis, nosql

My understanding is that using Redis requires you to host it on its own server. So why even use it if the data being stored on it isn't being run on the same VM (thus using the same RAM) as your app server (eg Node)?

Answer (score 4):

You're not required to host Redis on a separate server at all. In fact, it's not uncommon for application servers to run an in-memory store like Redis or Memcached on the same server for simple caching tasks.

However, what I think is at the heart of your question is a fundamental misunderstanding of how in-memory storage works. Even if you were to run Redis on the same server as your application, your application would never be able to directly access the RAM blocks that Redis uses to store your data--you would still need to send a request to the Redis instance to retrieve the data. Hosting Redis separately from your application server does introduce network latency, but there's zero difference in terms of accessing or modifying the data in RAM.

Comment: I'm confused. It was my understanding that these "in-memory" DBs were fast because they permitted a faster access to storage (cache instead of main memory). If you take a look at latency numbers you see that a network request is way more expensive than main memory access, which by itself is way more expensive than cache references. In other words, isn't the main benefit of Redis it's fast memory access completely undermined if you envolve network latency?

Comment: @AlexRamalho The purpose of an in-memory database is not to leverage cache memory over main memory or to remove network latency from the equation, but to replace the data access latency associated with traditional filesystem-based databases while still providing a shared remote datastore. In-memory databases are almost universally slower than storing in local cache or main memory from your application directly; they were never designed for that purpose.

Comment: Fair enough. But getting back to the original question – it does not make sense to run Redis or Memcached if its on the same server. 

You said "it's not uncommon for application servers to run an in-memory store like Redis or Memcached on the same server for simple caching tasks", but again, since memory is volatile anyways, and if you're in the same server, just use direct memory access as it will be quicker.

Answer (score 2):

The name "Redis" is an acronym for REmote DIctionary Server - the "Remote" part indicates that it is intended to be used over a network. The main concept here is that the data stored in memory in Redis is accessible to multiple application instances, instead of having an in-app store for each.

That said, there is no requirement to have Redis on a separate server or use it with multiple application instance. On the other hand, it makes a lot of sense because that is what it was designed for.

Comment: So then is the data bottleneck in retrieval from storage (which is alleviated through memory with Redis) rather than the network?